# how to print Map[String, Array[Float]] in scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, word2vec

I am using word2vec function which is inside mllib library of Spark. I want to print word vectors which I am getting as output to "getVectors" function
My code looks like this:

```
import org.apache.spark._

import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.{Word2Vec, Word2VecModel}

object word2vec {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("word2vec")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val input = sc.textFile("file:///home/snap-01/balance.csv").map(line => line.split(",").toSeq)
    val word2vec = new Word2Vec()
    val model = word2vec.fit(input)
    model.save(sc, "myModelPath")
    val sameModel = Word2VecModel.load(sc, "myModelPath")
    val vec = sameModel.getVectors
    print(vec)
  }
}
```

I am getting "**Map(Balance -> [F@2932e15f)**"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
vec.foreach { case (key, values) => println("key " + key + " - " + values.mkString("-"))
}
```

Comment: Add ')': vec.foreach { case (key, values) => println("key " + key + " - " + values.mkString("-")) }

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

```
println(vec.mapValues(_.toList))
```

But keep an eye on the memory required to do so.